# Flume fails on config file

Tags: flume

I have some code I inherited and there is little documentation. The system keeps failing on various errors. It seems to me it is not reading the jar files and I am not even sure where it is looking. Here is the error below. Can anyone offer any advice?

```
     - Creating instance of source Twitter, type uk.co.senym.flume.TweetDataSource
    13 Dec 2013 15:29:55,923 ERROR [conf-file-poller-0](org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:142)  - Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
    org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load source type: uk.co.senym.flume.TweetDataSource, class: uk.co.senym.flume.TweetDataSource
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:327)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.senym.flume.TweetDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at                                         org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:65)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of Flume then you should use the plugins.d directory.

I'll assume for the moment you are using a Bigtop-derived distribution such as Cloudera CDH4. Then you want to take a look @ /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume-env.sh to see if they were customizing the Flume classpath to point to the jar file for your custom twitter source.

That is the old way and it kinda sucks. A better way is to put your stuff into plugins.d as documented here: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/flume-ng/FlumeUserGuide.html#installing-third-party-plugins

I believe the default plugins.d directory on CDH4 is /var/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d

HTH

Comment: Hi Mike, I have the same problem. I am not using CDH4. I have downloaded and installed flume-1.6.0 . I don't have plugins.d directory under flume. Can you please help me rectify this error